# Abrir modal aumaticamente

Tags: javascript

saben como se podria lograr esto, puramente con javascript, porque intente con un ejemplo de aqui y no me funciona.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#modal1').modal('modal-trigger')
});
```

```html
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Si yo hago clic si funciona, pero si quiero que aparezca automaticamente no, como podría hacerlo?

**AGREGO:**

Estoy usando la librería base de Materializecss: https://materializecss.com/

Comment: Intenta con $('#modal1').modal('show');

Comment: Saludos, no, parece no funcionar, crees que hay alguna funcion que no se cual es que hay que llamar?

Comment: ya abriste inspeccionar elemento en el navegador y chocaste que no te muestre error en tu código JS?

Comment: primero checa que este entrando a tu $( document ).ready(function() { y coloca dentro un alert() para validar

Answer (score 2):

Funciona correctamente, probablemente solo te falta agregar las librerías de [jQuery Modal](https://jquerymodal.com/). Adicionalmente, el enlace o botón que abre el modal debe tener el siguiente atributo: `rel="modal:open"`

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#modal1').modal('modal-trigger')
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!-- link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/ -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>

<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1" rel="modal:open">Modal</a>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat" rel="modal:close">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Gracias, funciona, pero al incluir otros estilos, y .js me cambio un poco el diseño de lo que ya programé, se puede hacer sin incluir otros archivos?

Comment: De hecho, puedes omitir los estilos e incluir solo el `.js`, acabo de editar la pregunta para no cargar estilos de _jQuery Modal_

Comment: Ahi estoy probando, pero en mi archivo .css del materialize tengo unos estilos mios, tendria que volver a agregarlos a esta librería, porque con la mia, que es la base de materialize no me funciona

Comment: No es buena idea sobreescribir librerías (estilos o javascript), necesitas crear tu propia hoja de estilos aparte. Ya sería cuestión de aplicar mayor [especifidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad) a tus estilos o caer en la mala práctica de usar `!important`

Comment: Tambien veo que no es lo mismo que al abrir yo con el boton, porque si es con el boton, el boton "agree" funciona, ademas el fondo está un poco oscuro, creo que no me sirve tampoco.

Comment: Sí funciona, solo hay que incluir los atributos necesarios de acuerdo a la librería; en este caso, solo agregar `rel="modal:close"` al enlace _Agree_. En cuanto al fondo oscuro, es parte de los estilos propios de _Materialize_.

Comment: No me convence como queda, porque ya no estoy usando jquery, y no me gustaría integrarlo, pero estoy en una version que uso https://material-ui.com/es/components/dialogs/ ya funcionando, sabes si se puede hacer aca, o creo otro tema?

Answer (score 0):

Si dieras un poco más de información de la librería que usas para el modal, tal vez pueda ayudarte mejor, pero puedes intentar con algo así:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('.modal-trigger').click();
});
```

Podrías colocarlo dentro de un timer para que se ejecutará después de X segundos.

Comment: Gracias, parece que eso no funcionó, sin embargo, edite el tema, y agregue la libreria que estoy usando.

Answer (score 0):

> Botón que dispara función que abre modal

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="abrirModal()">Abrir modal</button>
```

> Modal

```html
<div id="mi-modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Función que muestra modal

```js
function abrirModal(){
    $('#mi-modal').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: Gracias, ahi lo pruebo, pero creo que no me serviria, porque ya tengo mis estilos, y mi javascript. Ahi agregué en el tema la libreria.